# Avocado seedling too late to save?

Tags: seedlings, fungus

I started growing my avocado seedling a few months ago. it’s seemingly been growing fine and I haven’t seen any concerning things. I’m a newbie in gardening and I checked my roots today and It seems to be puffy fungi growing all over and in the seedling. On the roots it looks like a splitting almost in the skin of the root and there is puffy white stuff growing all inside the seed. Is it too late to save? or is this normal? I’ve tried scraping it off and running it under water but it hasn’t come off.[image]

Comment: Many plant roots have symbiotic relationships with fungi (even if this isn't.) You might want to relax and drop "try to kill anything you don't understand" as a first reaction to plant oddities you happen to notice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhiza If you live somewhere that you could expect to grow your avocado outside, consider moving out of water, which is not a normal habitat (except for several million avocado pits that will never make it as far as producing an avocado in colder climates, and even they would prefer potting mix in a LARGE pot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal for an avocado sprouted in water. There is no need to do anything. The 'fungus' is the root adapting to water